# How to convert a Akka LoggingAdapter to a SLF4J Logger

Tags: akka

I am using akka LoggingAdapter instances inside my actors to log, but i have some library code that i am calling from an actor, that takes a SLF4J Logger instance as parameter.

Is there an easy way to convert or wrap the LoggingAdapter, so that i can pass it to the library code as a SLF4J Logger.

I could write such a wrapper by hand, but i think it sounds like a pretty normal use case, so I thought that there mayby is a way to do this already, that I just had no luck finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper class, that implements the Slf4j Logger interface, and delegates all calls to a wrapped LoggingAdapter. The [class](https://bitbucket.org/cirque/util-akka-logging/src/aae0322c1b498419c6031e506c7e4706d080563e/src/main/scala/dk/cirque/util/akka/logging/Slf4jLoggingAdapterWrapper.scala?at=default) can be found in [this project on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/cirque/util-akka-logging)

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a slf4j logger with

```
   Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
```

and pass it to your library. Regardless if you use Akka slf4j logger or not.

Comment: I know, but as far as i know, that would create a blocking logger instacne, or at least that would be depending on the slf4j implementation in use. I think (correct me if im wrong) that the main reason for akka to have created its own logging system, is to make the logging async, so that it is safe to call from an actor. I would really like to reuse this, as i call the library code from my actor, and know that logging is the only potential blocking operation that it performs.

Comment: Akka slf4j logger just calls slf4j somewhere down the line. Maybe you obtain reference to underlying slf4j. That reference wouldn't be any less blocking than if you created it with LoggerFactory. It's more a question what does your library do with the logger.

Comment: Log statements that is created though akka own logging system, is sendt though the event strem, and picked up by an actor that should do the actually logging. That could be the akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler class, that logs to slf4j. This gives two advantages over creating an sfl4j logger directly. It makes the logging async, and therefor the requester won't have to wait on slow logging, and it can potentially run on another dispatcher, and thereby avoid starvation problems on the dispatcher used by the other actors, in case that the disk is slow, and the logs is blocking a long time.

Comment: You want something like slf4j over akka. Perhaps you can implement one ?

Comment: Implementing a full akka based implementation of a SLF4J backend would be to much work for solving this problem for me. I think i will go for a little class that implements the org.slf4j.Logger interface, and delegates all the actual logging to a wrapped akka logger. I just hoped that there was some standard solution that i had not ben able to find.